# How to remove empty lines to one empty line between sentences in text files?

Tags: sed, grep, gawk

I have a text file with many empty lines between sentences. I used sed, gawk, grep but they dont work. :(. How can I do now? Thanks.

```
Myfile:         Desired file:
a                    a
b                    b
c                    c
.                    .

d                    d
e                    e
f                    f
g                    g
.                    .

                     h
                     i
h                    j
i                    k
j                    .
k
.
```

Comment: Alice, given that both high-scoring answers (mine and Cyrus') work fine under CygWin, it's looking more like some other problem. Are you sure those lines are blank, as opposed to having some spaces in them? If they do, there's a slight mod to my answer (which will also work for Cyrus') to collapse lines with whitespace down to truly empty lines.

Comment: Thank you, @paxdiablo, I will try to find some other problems in my file. I tried to use sed to make them all truly empty lines but it doesnt work. Thanks for your helps. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{prev="x"}
     /^$/ {if (prev==""){next}}
          {prev=$0;print}'       inputFile
```

or the compressed one liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{p="x"}/^$/{if(p==""){next}}{p=$0;print}' inFl
```

This is a simple state machine that collapses multi-blank-lines into a single one.

The basic idea is this. First, set the previous line to be non-empty.

Then, for every line in the file, if it and the previous one are blank, just throw it away.

Otherwise, set the previous line to that value, print the line, and carry on.

Sample transcript, the following command:

```
$ echo '1
2
3
4
5

6
7
8
9


10' | awk 'BEGIN{p="x"}/^$/{if(p==""){next}}{p=$0;print}'
```

outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5

6
7
8
9

10
```

---

Keep in mind that this is for *truly* blank lines (no content). If you're trying to collapse lines that have an arbitrary number of spaces or tabs, that will be a little trickier.

In that case, you could pipe the file through something like:

```
sed 's/^\s*$//'
```

to ensure lines with just whitespace become truly empty.

In other words, something like:

```
sed 's/^\s*$//' infile | awk 'my previous awk command'
```

Comment: Thanks @paxdiablo! But it doesnt work well. output file I received is an empty file. I used gawk instead of  awk because my system is GNU.

Comment: @Alice, it was _tested_ with `gawk` - `GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2, GNU MP 6.0.0)` so, if there''s something wrong, I suspect it may be with your file or invocation. You _are_ using your specific filename rather than my sample `inputFile`, yes?

Comment: yes, First, I used my own data, but then I tried both two your commands with my sample file above but I received: 
<code> 
?a
b
c
.
</code>

Comment: @Alice: cut and paste your exact command used into a comment box, and show the output of `od -xcb yourInputFile`. The fact that it's working for me but not you suggests an environment issue.

Comment: My commands is that: [link] C\user\thegioiso\Downloads\...\SRL data>gawk 'BEGIN{p="x"}/^$/{if(p==""){next}} {p=$0;print}' input.txt > new.txt'
input.txt is my sample above.
new.txt is my output file, I received:
a
b
c
.

Comment: @Alice, if you're using native `gawk`, you're subject to `cmd` shell limitations. You may have to escape the `^` character as `^^`.

Comment: You means: `gawk 'BEGIN{p="x"}/^^$/{if(p==""){next}} {p=$0;print}' input.txt ` I used Cygwin but the output is the same as input.

Comment: @Alice, that's not native. CygWin is what I used so it should be fine with what I provided.

Answer (score 2):

To suppress repeated empty output lines with GNU cat:

```
cat -s file1 > file2
```

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus. But I received the orginal file with your commands.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this also,

```
awk -v RS="\0" '{gsub(/\n\n+/,"\n\n");}1' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `RS="\0"` Once we set the null character as Record Seperator value, awk will read the whole file as single record.
- `gsub(/\n\n+/,"\n\n");` this replaces one or more blank lines with a single blank line. Note that `\n\n` regex matches a blank line along with the previous line's new line character.

Comment: Thanks @Avinash Rai, i used gawk instead of awk because of my GNU system. It's noticed that:
gawk: cmd. line:1: \0
gawk: cmd. line:1 :^ backslash not last character on line

Comment: This may well solve the problem, but it would be great if you could give a bit more explanation as to how/why it solves the problem. Don't forget there are heaps of rank-newbies on S/O and what may be obvious to you may not be to them. They could learn a thing or two from you if you give them the chance :)

Comment: @Alice `gawk -v RS="\0" '{gsub(/\n\n+/,"\n\n");}1' file`, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `sed`:

```
sed ':a; N; $!ba; s/\n\n\+/\n\n/g' file
```

Otherwise, if you don't mind a trailing blank line, all you need is:

```
awk '1' RS= ORS="\n\n" file
```

---

The Perl solution is even shorter:

```
perl -00 -pe '' file
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve but three of them seem not work for me. I received a file same to input with one or two extra empty lines at the end file.

Comment: @Alice: You probably need to run `dos2unix file` first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other `awk`

```
awk -v p=1 'p=="" {p=1;next} 1; {p=$0}' file
```